# nuget package created with serilog 2.10 raise a file not found serilog version 2.0.0 error

Tags: nuget, serilog, .net-standard

I've created a simple .Net standard 2.1 logger nuget package containing serilog 2.10. The package work well when referenced has a project but fail with wrong serilog version when used has a nuget package with another projet.
I've tried downgrading to .Net standard 2.0 with no success.
I packed the project with the parameter -IncludeReferencedProjects but no luck.

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Thanks

Comment: [You need to provide more details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What does "fail with wrong serilog version" mean, exactly? Do you get a compilation error? Runtime error? What is the exact error message? Providing a screenshot also helps. The best way to for others to help you is if you provide a sample project and upload to GitHub that anyone here can see and reproduce the error on their machines.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I was using nuget.exe and it was not including dependencies.After trying many configs it didn't work. I ended using msbuild /t:pack and eveything is OK now.